# Can you use break to validate input in python?

Tags: python, string, validation, input

Like using this to validate that an input is only alpha-numeric:

```
while True:
    str = input('')
    if str.isalnum():
        break
    else:
        print("Please include only alpha-numeric characters.\n")
```

This code has worked for all instances that I have tested it in, but is this bad practice?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code (except for the fact that `str` is a builtin and you should not shadow it with a variable)

Comment: That is a good example of how to use a break, it is not bad practice.

Comment: This is actually the recommended practice. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response/23294659#23294659)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine.  Here is a note, however: you can find out if the `while` loop exited with a `break` or without one by using `else`:

```
x = 0
while x < 4:
    x += 1
else:
    print("no break")

# prints no break
```

If you break, however:

```
x = 0
while x < 4:
    x += 1
    if x == 2:
        break
else:
    print("no break")

# Does not print
```

Answer (score -2):

you can abstract it further

```
def verified_input(prompt='',test_condition=lambda x:1,err_message="Please Enter Valid Input"):
    while True:
        result = input(prompt)
        if test_condition(result):
           return result
        print( err_message )


def verified_alnum(prompt,err_message="Please enter Only alpha numerics"):
      return verified_input(prompt,lambda x:x.isalnum(),err_message)



result = verified_alnum("Enter Password:","A password must be only letters and numbers")
```

this allows you to create any number of test conditions quickly and relatively verbosely

Comment: Technically correct, but very overcomplicated compared to the question asked.